# Powershell replace with wild card

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I want to replace a domain string

"random.org" to take everything after and the full stop

```
$newstring = $domain.replace #Not sure what else to add
```

I know to use .Replace, but not sure how to use the wildcard feature and how it works.

Can I have a little help please!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell's "-replace" operator, which is used with regex is often confused with ".replace" method on strings. There are many way you can skin that cat, but your question is a bit vague to answer precisely.

Regardless, in your case you do not want to use the "method"

```
string.replace()
```

instead use, as others suggested, the "operator"

```
string -replace "regex_to_be_replaced_here", "replacement_here"
```

A couple of examples have been provided already. I would go with Joey's, where his regex says "start from the beginning of the string and match everything except a dot (".") and replace them with nothing, effectively erasing them leaving the parts after dot behind:

```
$newstring = $domain -replace '^[^.]*', ''
```

You might also be able to use .split method or -split operator

```
string.split("some_delim") or string -split "some_delim"
```

Example:

```
$domain = "random.org"    
$domain.split('.')[-1]
org
```

split operator, like -replace operator uses regex, where '.' has a special meaning, so you need to escape it, telling regex that you really want to match a '.'

```
 ($domain -split '\.')[-1]
 org
```

If you already know how many characters from the right side of the string you need, you may even use substring(). Following means give me the last 3 chars of $domain:

```
$domain.substring($domain.length - 3)
org
```

Comment: Sorry, obviously I didn't write it clear enough. I want it to be the other way round - so I get rid of the TLD and keep the website name

Eg.

Google.com >> Google

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell's `-replace` operator, which uses regular expressions:

```
$newstring = $domain -replace '^[^.]*'
```

If you're wondering about the lack of the replacement string, that is optional in PowerShell; above code is functionally identical to

```
$newstring = $domain -replace '^[^.]*', ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking only the TLD (.com, .org, .gov, etc.), then you can use -replace with a capture.

```
PS C:\src\t> "www.myhome.org"  -replace '^[^.]*'
.myhome.org
PS C:\src\t> "www.myhome.org"  -replace '^.*(\..*)', '$1'
.org
```